# How to compare lists of custom classes without defining equals() and hashCode()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert, equality

Since defining `equals()` and `hashCode()` only for testing purpose is considered as a code smell, I prefer to use `ReflectionEquals` or custom matchers to compare objects while doing unit testing.

However, I don't know how to use `ReflectionEquals` or custom matchers in comparing lists of user-defined classes.

For example, how do I assert the following code without defining `equals()` and `hashCode()` (maybe only use `ReflectionEquals` or custom matchers)?

```java
// When
List<Record> actual = sut.findBySomeId();

// Then
List<Record> expected = asList(
    aRecord()...build(), 
    aRecord()...build()
);
assertThat(expected, /* how to compare? */);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a super fluent library for solving your issue, called [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). It is quite easy to use, flexible to make changes and its fluency makes the tests easy to read!
In order to use it, first you have to import the right package

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
```

I do not know how your `Record` model looks like, so I made a dummy one:

```
public class Record {
    private String name;
    private String data;
    private String history;

    public Record(String name, String data, String history) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
        this.history = history;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getHistory() {
        return history;
    }

}
```

Then the test would like like, if you only want to assert list of `Record` based on one field:

```
@Test
public void give_when_then() throws Exception {
    List<Record> actualList = sut.findBySomeId();

    assertThat(actualList)
            .extracting(record -> record.getData())
            .containsExactly("data1", "data2", "data3");
}
```

If you want to assert the objects based on multiple fields, you can do for example:

```
@Test
public void give_when_then() throws Exception {
    List<Record> actualList = sut.findBySomeId();

    assertThat(actualList)
            .extracting(
                    record -> record.getName(),
                    record -> record.getHistory())
            .containsExactly(
                    tuple("name1", "history1"),
                    tuple("name2", "history2"),
                    tuple("name3", "history3"));
}
```

...where tuple is also an assert4J object for wrapping the results.

Furthermore there are bunch of assert methods like `containsExactlyInAnyOrder(...)`, `containsAll(...)`, `containsAnyOf(...)` etc., which could also help your life in certain cases.

Last but not least you can also write your own specific object assert class extending `AbstractObjectAssert` base class. With this you will have (among others) a method called `isEqualToComparingFieldByField`. From the [official documentation](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html):

> Assert that actual object is equal to the given object based on a property/field by property/field comparison (including inherited ones). **This can be handy if equals implementation of objects to compare does not suit you**.

First you define your own assert class:

```
public class RecordAssert extends AbstractObjectAssert<RecordAssert, Record> {

    public RecordAssert(Record actual) {
        super(actual, RecordAssert.class);
    }

}
```

Then the usage of it would look like:

```
@Test
public void give_when_then() throws Exception {
    List<Record> actual = sut.findBySomeId();

    assertThat(actual.get(0)).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(new Record("name1", "data1", "history1"));
    // Asserts for other objects

}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I was exploring the AssertJ library and there are some very convenient methods like [usingComparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html#usingComparator-java.util.Comparator-) and [usingElementComparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html#usingElementComparator-java.util.Comparator-). So you can do something like 
 ```assertThat(actualList).usingElementComparator(yourCustomComparator).isEqualTo(expectedList);```

Answer (score 4):

The Hamcrest library has a great selection of matchers for making assertions on collections types.  In particular, the [`hasItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsCollectionContaining.html#hasItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher)), [`hasItems`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsCollectionContaining.html#hasItems(org.hamcrest.Matcher...)), [`contains`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(java.util.List)) and [`containsAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(org.hamcrest.Matcher...)) matchers as these can use matchers themselves (I like to use [TypeSafeMatcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.html)) to test the items in the collections.

I'll leave you to decide which one best suits your needs, but I'll use `contains` for my example:

```
List<Record> actual = sut.findBySomeId();

Record expected1 = aRecord()...build();
Record expected2 = aRecord()...build();

assertThat(actual, contains(matchingRecord(expected1), matchingRecord(expected2));

...

// somewhere the test has access to it
private Matcher<Record> matchingRecord(Record expected) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<Record>() {
        public boolean matchesSafely(Record actual) {
            // perform tests and return result, e.g.
            return actual.getValue() == expected.getValue();
        }

        public void describeMismatchSafely(Record record, Description mismatchDescription) {
            mismatchDescription.appendText("give a meaningful message");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thought I would add that there is no reason you couldn't use `ReflectionEquals` in the `matchesSafely` method of the `Matcher`

Answer (score 2):

I would say that using Reflection for checking `equals`/`hashCode` is another code smell in itself.

With `Matcher`, you must do something like that (I used the fully qualified name for clarity, use `import` instead): this will check that the `value` of `result` is the same as the one from `expected`. You can add as much field as you need.

```
assertThat(result, new org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher<MyObject>() {
  public boolean matches(MyObject o) {
    return java.lang.Objects.equals(o.getValue(), expected.getValue());
  }
});
```

If you don't want to create a getter for the field of your class, then use default visibility (that what's does Guava and they annotate such fields with  `@VisibleForTesting`).

You might also take a look at [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) to create custom and fluent matchers (it works more or less the same).

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue in the past and I am totally agree with you that implementing the `equals()` and `hashCode()` for only testing purpose is a code smell. I do not use Hamcrest library so I will provide you a custom solution which I successfully use in my projects and as for its usage I am quite pleased with it.

```
public static <E, A> void assertListEquals(BiConsumer<E, A> asserter, List<E> expected, List<A> actual) throws AssertionError {
    assertEquals(
            "Lists have different sizes. Expected list: " + expected + ",  actual list: " + actual,
            expected.size(),
            actual.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
        try {
            asserter.accept(expected.get(i), actual.get(i));
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, a BiConsumer is used in order to apply the logic for checking the equality of two objects. So this one has to be implemented in the test class. The advantage of it is that you can define the fields of a class you are interested in when comparing two objects.

Lets see the usage of it:
First we have a custom class, f.e.: Person

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then lets see a test method:

```
@Test
public void peopleLiveInTheVillage_findPeople_peopleAreFound() throws Exception {
    //Arrange
    List<Person> expectedPeople = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Lewis", "Smith", 20),
            new Person("Steven", "Richard", 25),
            new Person("Richie", "Rich", 30));

    //Act
    List<Person> actualPeople = sut.findPeople();

    //Assert
    assertListEquals(
            (e, a) -> assertPersonEquals(e, a),
            expectedPeople,
            actualPeople);
}

private void assertPersonEquals(Person expected, Person actual) {
    assertEquals(expected.getFirstName(), actual.getFirstName());
    assertEquals(expected.getLastName(), actual.getLastName());
    assertEquals(expected.getAge(), actual.getAge());
}
```

Since I am a big fan of tests (and TDD) I always write tons of tests so I always make a helper method where I wrap the BiConsumer:

```
private void assertPeopleEqual(List<Person> expectedPeople, List<Person> actualPeople) throws AssertionError {
    assertListEquals(
            (e, a) -> assertPersonEqual(e, a),
            expectedPeople,
            actualPeople);
}
```

I hope this helps, cheers!